# conditional OR never works when comparing two strings

Tags: c#, datatable, conditional-statements

I have a DataTable with some basic address information.  I am trying to remove any states that are not New York or Pennsylvania.

So, this works fine:

```
foreach (DataRow row in uwDataTable.Rows)
{
    if (row[15].ToString() != "New York" || )
    {
        rowsToDelete.Add(row);
    }
}
```

However, this deletes EVERY row:

```
foreach (DataRow row in uwDataTable.Rows)
{
    if (row[15].ToString() != "New York" || row[15].ToString() != "Pennsylvania")
    {
        rowsToDelete.Add(row);
    }
}
```

This seems really simple, but for whatever reason, the "not equal" is picking up too much.

Comment: Like the riddle, I have two coins that equal 30 cents and one of them is not a nickel.  A quarter is not a nickel so a quarter and a nickel satisfies the conditions.  In your sample, Pennsylvania is not New York, and New York is not Pennsylvania, so they both meet the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ORs  (`||`) should be ANDs (`&&`).

That is giving you all the items and you want to delete te specific ones.

Something like this...

```
if (row[15].ToString() != "New York" && row[15].ToString() != "Pennsylvania")
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your quick responses.

Answer (score 10):

The reason why

```
row[15].ToString() != "New York" || row[15].ToString() != "Pennsylvania"
```

deletes every row is that `row[15].ToString()` cannot be equal two different strings at the same time, therefore at least one of the two "not equals" is going to evaluate to `true`, making the overall `OR` evaluate to `true` as well.

You are looking for `&&`, not `||` in that condition:

```
row[15].ToString() != "New York" && row[15].ToString() != "Pennsylvania"
```

This one will be `true` only when both "not equals" evaluate to `true`, i.e. the state is not New York and the state is not Pennsylvania.

Comment: Of course by [De Morgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws), `if (row[15].ToString() != "New York" && row[15].ToString() != "Pennsylvania")` is the same as `if (!(row[15].ToString() == "New York" || row[15].ToString() == "Pennsylvania"))`, meaning it is neither New York nor Pennsylvania.

Answer (score 5):

You want to check if it not `Pennsylvania` and if it is not `New York` so you have to use `&&` (AND) not `||` (OR);

```
foreach (DataRow row in uwDataTable.Rows)
{
    if ((row[15].ToString() != "New York") && (row[15].ToString() != "Pennsylvania"))
    {
          rowsToDelete.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your delete method is deleting every row that either isn't "New York" or isn't "Pennsylvania". Since something that is New York cannot also be Pennsylvania (and vice versa), the OR condition will always be satisfied and the row will be marked for deletion.

You probably want to be using an AND instead:

```
if (row[15].ToString() != "New York" && row[15].ToString() != "Pennsylvania")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should actually be using an AND here;

```
 if (row[15].ToString() != "New York" && row[15].ToString() != "Pennsylvania")
```

You want a row that is not New York and is not Penn. With the or, both new york and penn will evaluate to true.

True or false == true

penn != new york == true AND new york != penn == true

therefor you will always get true.

Answer (score 2):

You should use AND operator

OR executes even if only one condition is TRUE. So for "New York", the 2nd condition will be true and it will be deleted.

Whereas AND will execute only if both are TRUE,

```
if (row[15].ToString() != "New York" && row[15].ToString() != "Pennsylvania")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in uwDataTable.Rows)
            {
                if (!row[15].ToString().ToLower().Equals("new york") && !row[15].ToLower().Equals("pennsylvania"))
                {
                    rowsToDelete.Add(row);
                }
            }
```